# Segmentation fault in c program,use malloc (Linux os)

Tags: c, linux

this c program works in Windows But Getting " Segmentation fault (core dump)" in Linux. I gues couse of error pointers or malloc function.I can't return struct array without pointers and malloc.

```
struct team {
    char name[12];
    int m_count;
    int score;
};

struct team *teamName(){        

    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen("teams.txt", "r");

    struct team *items; 
    items= (struct team *) malloc(sizeof(struct team) * 10);

    int i;
    for(i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        fscanf(fp, "%s\n" , items[i].name); 
    }

    fclose(fp);
    return items;
}

int main(void)
{   struct team *items = teamName();    
    getMatch(items);
}
```

Comment: Why are you casting the pointer returned by `malloc()`? When you debugged your code with gdb, where did the segfault occur? What does `getMatch()` do?

Comment: I debugged code and  error occurs when the teamName() function is finished. actually the code is very long i didn'n write all. getMatc func must use this struct array.

Comment: if i don't use malloc it doesn't work.I don't know the reason.I'm so new in c. @PierceGriffiths

Comment: How about adding some checks, for example whether `fopen` succeeded. Are there team names that exceed 11 characters?

Comment: no there aren't

Comment: I didn't say that you shouldn't use `malloc()`, I'm saying that you shouldn't cast the pointer that it returns unless you're writing in C++. C has automatic pointer promotion, and casting malloc'd pointers can prevent the compiler from issuing warnings.

Comment: @kubra the problem is probably not the _malloc_ by itself, look at my answer

Comment: Read [*How to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and read [about undefined behavior](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html)

Answer (score 1):

There several problems in your code :

- you do not check *fopen* success
- you do not check *fscanf* success, and if a read name is greater than 11 you write out of the buffer with an undefined behavior
- why the `\n` in the *fscanf* format ?
- if you read less that 10 names some entries are not set, with the risk later to have an undefined behavior

---

A proposal taking my remarks into account can be :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct team {
  char name[12];
  int m_count;
  int score;
};

struct team *teamName(){        
  FILE *fp = fopen("teams.txt", "r");

  if (fp == NULL)
    return NULL;

  struct team *items = malloc(sizeof(struct team) * 10);

  int i;

  for (i=0; i<10; i++)
  {
    if (fscanf(fp, "%11s" , items[i].name) != 1) {
      /* empty other names */
      do {
        items[i].name[0] = 0;
      }
      while (++i != 10);
      break;
    }
  }

  fclose(fp);
  return items;
}

int main(void)
{
  struct team *items = teamName();

  if (items != NULL) {
    for (int i = 0; i != 10; ++i) {
      if (items[i].name[0] != 0)
        puts(items[i].name);
    }
  }

  /* getMatch(items); */
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -pedantic -Wextra -Wall m.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ cat teams.txt 
aze qsd
loop
bar
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
aze
qsd
loop
bar
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

Note the *fscanf* read words, I mean a name must not contain space, else you need to use for instance *fgets*

Comment: sorry. still getting the same error. Segmentation fault (core dump)

Comment: @kubra as you can see my proposal works, what did you do ?